# Does this integral identity hold?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**Problem**: Let $f$ be a radial function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x) = f(|x|).$ Then I want to verify if the following holds for all indices $i, j$ and $k.$
$$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \partial_{x_ix_j}f(x)\partial_{x_k}f(x) dx = 0.$$

**Proof attempt**: Since $f$ is radial, denote $r = |x|$ and therefore,
$$\partial_{x_i} f(x)  = \frac{x_i}{r}f'(r), \partial_{x_ix_j}f(x) = \frac{f'(r)}{r}\delta_{ij}+\left(\frac{f''(r)}{r^2}-\frac{f'(r)}{r^3}\right)x_ix_j.$$
Then
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \partial_{x_ix_j}f(x)\partial_{x_k}f(x) dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left[\frac{f'(r)}{r}\delta_{ij}+\left(\frac{f''(r)}{r^2}-\frac{f'(r)}{r^3}\right)x_ix_j\right]  \frac{x_k}{r}f'(r) dx \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{x_k \delta_{ij}}{r^2}[f'(r)]^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{x_{i}x_{j}x_k}{r^3}f''(r)f'(r) - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{x_{i}x_{j}x_k}{r^4}[f'(r)]^2 dx\\
&= I_{1} + I_2 + I_3.
\end{align}
If $i\neq j$ then $I_1=0$ otherwise $I_1=0$ since the integrand is an odd function wrt. the variable $x_k.$

If $i,j$ and $k$ are distinct then $I_2$ is clearly odd in those variables. If any two indices are equal then the integrand is odd in the other variable so $I_2=0.$ If all indices are equal then still the integral is odd in $i=j=k$ variable and so $I_2 =0.$

Applying the same reasoning also implies that $I_3 = 0.$

I am not sure if this reasoning is correct, any suggestion/comments are much appreciated.

Comment: The notation $f(x) = f(|x|)$ is very confusing (and if you think about it slightly, it is completely illogical: how can $f$ on the LHS eat an element of $\Bbb{R}^n$ while on the RHS it eats a real number?); it is much clearer to introduce a new letter, by saying there is a function $\phi:\Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to \Bbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in \Bbb{R}^n$, $f(x) = \phi(|x|)$. Also, it's clear from the derivative expressions that the first partial derivatives are odd functions of $x$, while the second partial derivatives are even functions of $x$.

Comment: Hence, their product is odd, and this is enough to deduce that the integral (assuming everything converges etc) is $0$. There is no need to have the integrand be odd with respect to a particular $x_i$.